# How to run 2 .exe files using registry keys

Tags: registrykey

The idea here is to make 2 .exe files run when I open only 1 of them.

I have 2 files:

- F:\Gry\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\OverwolfLauncher.exe

When I launch **LeagueClient.exe** I'd like **OverwolfLauncher.exe** to run alongside it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Either modify `LeagueClient.exe` to launch the other exe, or create a bat file to call them both.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to modify the LeagueClient without running with any issues with the anticheat, I believe creating a bat file would be what you want.

```
@ECHO off
start F:\Gry\Riot Games\League of Legends\LeagueClient.exe
start C:\Program Files (x86)\Overwolf\OverwolfLauncher.exe
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's a better way of doing it